# xcode swift for [[[view class] description]

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I want to get the uiview's class description in **xcode swift** for below code in tableview's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewIndex"]){
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is direct translation in swift based from the question.

```
if NSStringFromClass(view.classForCoder) == "UITableViewIndex"
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, that `isEqualToSTring` is not the best option in your case. I can think of two better options:

```
if view.isKindOfClass(UITableViewIndex) {
    ...
}
```

Or, even better:

```
if let tableView = view as? UITableViewIndex {
    ... //Here you can use a tableView instead of view.
}
```

String comparison is not a fast operation. isKindOfClass / type casting should be faster. And you don't have to worry about typos in your strings. And you don't have to change those strings everywhere in case you want to refactor your code and rename your class.

**UPDATE**: as Nikolai Ruhe noted, `UITableViewIndex` is private (at first I thought that it is your custom subclass), so this technique can't be used in this case. Check out Allan's answer instead.

Comment: `UITableViewIndex` is private.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe, yes, it turns out, you're right. I thought that `UITableViewIndex` is the OP's custom `UITableView` subclass.

Comment: This technique is then inapplicable in the OP's case, but I'll leave the answer, because it might be useful for someone.